# Javascript infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

The example is pretty straight forward, I am trying to change focus button after button. What I was unable to do though is to have the whole process repeating from button one when its over.

```
var allButtons = $(":button");
for (i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            allButtons[index].focus(); 
        }, 1000*index);
    }(i));
}
```

---

```
<input type="button" value="Here" />
<input type="button" value="Here" />
<input type="button" value="Here" />
<input type="button" value="Here" />
<input type="button" value="Here" />
<input type="button" value="Here" />
```

---

```
input[type="button"]:focus { 
    color:red; 
}
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/95uBT/1/)

Comment: Please in include the code in your question instead of just linking. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use one `setInterval` function...

```
var index = -1;

setInterval(function() {
    index = (index + 1) % buttons.length;
    buttons[index].focus();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This will go through all the buttons once then fail when it reaches buttons.length + 1, no?

Comment: Close, but you accidentally skip the first button with this implementation on the first time through. Make sure you increment `index` after you set focus, not before.

Comment: @RwL: He's using the mod function to prevent that - keeps the index within the length of the buttons.

Comment: @Nightfirecat yes, but the first `.focus()` is on `buttons[1]`, which is actually the second button after `buttons[0]`

Comment: @Andrea Hare: Fixed. I like more the idea of having `index` being the last (i.e. current) focused button in case that is needed for other events... (with `index == -1` meaning no button has been focused yet).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is fairly simple: Recursion. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DduJU/

```
var allButtons = $(":button"),
    index = 0;
(function focus() {
    allButtons[index].focus();

    index++;
    setTimeout(focus, index*100);
    //this will be executed even though we called setTimeout
    //if index is larger than available buttons, restart it
    if (index >= allButtons.length)
        index = 0;
}());
```

I try to stay away from `setInterval`. In this example it may work fine, but `setInterval` will execute every n milliseconds even though the function may not complete in that time. In that case, function calls will stack. `setTimeout` is called here only after the major bulk of the function is complete, so even if for some reason it takes longer, you're still clear.

Comment: Your fear is wrong... `setInterval` only schedules for calls when the execution returns to the main event loop.